# How to navigate through the cells in jqgrid for a row on pressing tab key

Tags: java, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqgrid 3.8.2 with a few columns in it.I want to navigate through these cells on pressing tab key and when it reaches last column, it should perform validation of the current row and then move to the next row and repeat the same.In the current grid I have, pressing tab on a cell,is saving that row and moving to the next row, instead of navigating through the remaining cells in the row.How do I accomplish the same?

Please help.Here is the function that gets called on tab key down,

```
function actionOnTabKeyDown(event)
    {  var key = event.charCode || event.keyCode;  
        var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
        var nextRow = null;
        var validationStatus = null;     
        if (key == 9){
        { var currentDiv = event.target;
            for(var i= 0;i < ids.length;i++)
            {if(ids[i] == m_lastSelectedRow && (i != length - 1) )
                {nextRow = ids[i+1];
                 break;}}
           validationStatus = validateInput(m_lastSelectedRow);
           m_rowValidationStatus = validationStatus;
           if(validationStatus == 'pass') 
           {if(nextRow != null){   editRow(nextRow);m_lastSelectedRow = nextRow;}
               else{m_lastSelectedRow = null;}}        
           else if(validationStatus == 'ask')
           {
            //   alert("after validation ask");
               if(nextRow != null)
               {
                   nextSelectedRow = nextRow;
               } 
           }
           //if failed, keep the row as it is
        }//}
```